# Java:Delete all the elements from Linked List

Tags: java, linked-list

In Java, how to remove all the elements in linked list **without** using already available **`clear()`** method?  This exercise was inspired by a question received in a phone interview.

Say I can do this in C

```
void DeleteAllElement( ListElement **head ) {  
    ListElement *deleteMe = *head;  
    while( deleteMe )  {  
        ListElement *next = deleteMe->next;  
        delete deleteMe;  
        deleteMe = next;  
    }  
    *head = NULL;  
}
```

Thanks

Comment: Indent each line 4 spaces to get an automatic 'code' block. There is a tool to do this already: select the lines and click on the `{}` icon.

Comment: Deleted my answer, but really, why not use clear().  That's what it's there for.  Why reinvent the wheel?

Comment: Because i was asked in phone-interview

Comment: They would be more likely looking for bdares's answer

Answer (score 14, accepted):

Java has automatic garbage collection, so you just need to set the Head reference to null:

`myList.headNode = null;`

So, let's say we have the class `LinkedList`, which also has a `resetList` function...

```
public class LinkedList{
     private Node head;
     public Node find(Key k){ ... }
     public void add(Node n){ ... }
     ...
     public void reset(){ head = null;}
     public static void reset(LinkedList l){l.reset();}
}
```

If we are not making the `head` node private, we could simply execute the first code snippet I posted.

Comment: You need to set the list's reference to the head as null, not the passed reference.  `DeleteAllElement` should accept the list, not the head node, and set the list's head to `null`.  Otherwise the actual list keeps its reference to the existing head.

Comment: Care to put the wordings in form of code in your answer so i can accept it ?

Answer (score 8):

If you are talking about an instance of `java.util.LinkedList`:

```
    while (!linkedlist.isEmpty()) {
        linkedlist.removeFirst();
    }
```

If you are talking about an instance of any `java.util.List`:

```
    while (!list.isEmpty()) {
        list.remove(0);
    }
```

bearing in mind that `remove` is an optional operation.  However, depending on the list implementation, that could be horribly in efficient.  For an `ArrayList` this would be better:

```
    while (!list.isEmpty()) {
        list.remove(list.size() - 1);
    }
```

Another alternative would be to iterate the list and call `Iterator.remove()` on each element ... also an optional operation.  (But once again, that could be horribly inefficient for some list implementations.)

If you are talking about a custom linked list class, then the answer depends on the way you have declared the list classes internal data structures.

---

I suspect that if the interviewers mentioned the `clear()` method, they were expecting an answer in the context of the standard Java collection framework ... not a custom linked list class.

Answer (score 1):

```
for(i=0;i<linkedlist.size;i++){
  linkedlist.removeFirst();
}
```

or see [this example](http://www.java-forums.org/new-java/11947-linked-list-removeall-help.html).

Answer (score 1):

Reading the actual code is useful. I suggest you have a look.

For a singly linked list you can just do as @bdares, suggests when you look at the actual code for java.util.LinkedList (Which is what most developers use), the answer is rather different.

```
public void clear() {
    Entry<E> e = header.next;
    while (e != header) {
        Entry<E> next = e.next;
        e.next = e.previous = null;
        e.element = null;
        e = next;
    }
    header.next = header.previous = header;
    size = 0;
    modCount++;
}
```

First thing to note; this is doubly linked list for forward and backward traversal and it agressively clears all the references.  Not sure why it does this to be honist because the GC will clear thes eup any way and the `modCount` will pick up any changes in another thread. In fact it should really perform the modCount first.

For comparison, here is ArrayList.clear();

```
public void clear() {
    modCount++;

    // Let gc do its work
    for (int i = 0; i < size; i++)
        elementData[i] = null;

    size = 0;
}
```

Comment: *"Not sure why it does this ..."* - Short answer: generational GC. If a list node in an old generation refers to a node in a young generation, the former prevents the latter from being collected by the young generation collector.  This could lead to mass tenuring of unreachable list nodes.  Aggressive nulling avoids that.

Comment: (And the associated list elements ... which is probably more important than the nodes.)

Answer (score -1):

a couple of key points regarding the clearing of links between nodes in a linked list:

Generational Garbage Collection:

Some garbage collectors, including generational garbage collectors, work more efficiently when objects are cleared from all references. Generational garbage collectors divide objects into different generations based on their age.

Disconnecting all links between nodes helps in scenarios where discarded nodes may exist in more than one generation. By breaking all connections, it ensures that these nodes can be collected more effectively.

Reachability for Iterators:

Clearing links between nodes ensures that even if there is a reachable Iterator or other references, the nodes themselves are not reachable through the linked list structure. This guarantees that the nodes are eligible for garbage collection.

In some cases, objects might be indirectly referenced through iterators or other external references, and breaking internal links helps ensure that the nodes are not retained in memory due to such external references.

In practical terms, whether to clear all links between nodes depends on the specific requirements and characteristics of your application. If you are confident that there are no external references holding onto nodes, you might consider omitting this step for performance reasons. However, if you want to ensure that memory is reclaimed even in complex scenarios, clearing all links can be a conservative and safe approach.So in my  Point of view if you have even singlyLinked list and in program anywhere in any file if you have variable exist that referred directly or indirectly someRaddomVarible = head.next.next.next;   **then even if you null the head and tail the someRaddomVarible  is reachable and connected to links (directly or indirectly) which in turn GC will not delete the connected (directly or indirectly) object in RAM so i will consider better O(n) time complexity for any type of linked list.**

**Singly Linked List:**

```
public void clear() {

    // Disconnect all links between nodes

    LinkedListNode current = head;

    while (current != null) {

        LinkedListNode next = current.next;

        current.next = null;

        current = next;

    }

    

    // Set head to null

    head = null;

}
```

**Circular Linked List:**

```
public void clear() {

    if (head == null) {

        return; // Empty list

    }

    // Disconnect all links between nodes

    LinkedListNode current = head;

    do {

        LinkedListNode next = current.next;

        current.next = null;

        current = next;

    } while (current != head);

    

    // Set head to null

    head = null;

}
```

**Doubly Linked List:**

```
public void clear() {

    // Disconnect all links between nodes

    LinkedListNode current = head;

    while (current != null) {

        LinkedListNode next = current.next;

        // For doubly linked lists

        current.prev = null;

        current.next = null;

        current = next;

    }

    

    // Set head and tail to null

    head = null;

    // For doubly linked lists

    tail = null;

}
```

**Circular Doubly Linked List:**

```
public void clear() {
    // Disconnect all links between nodes
    LinkedListNode current = head;
    while (current != null) {
        LinkedListNode next = current.next;
        // For doubly linked lists
        current.prev = null;
        current.next = null;
        current = next;
    }
    
    // Set head and tail to null
    head = null;
    // For doubly linked lists
    tail = null;
}
```