# linked list deletion in java

Tags: java, linked-list

How do I delete a linked list completely in java. Some tutorials are suggesting that I should delete it node by node . But if I make head to null simply, would it be wrong ? As all the elements would be eligible for garbage collection.

Comment: Seems about right... if you set it to null, the GC will remove it... Or when you leave the context

Comment: whats wrong with lList.clear() ???

Comment: that removes the values, not the list itself

Comment: What are you trying to achieve? I never "deleted" a variable in Java and frankly do not see any sense in this. Just limit the scope of your variable and you do not have to care about this.

Comment: possible duplicate of [Delete unused variable's memory in java](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/11330812/delete-unused-variables-memory-in-java)

Comment: visit http://stackoverflow.com/questions/5658465/javadelete-all-the-elements-from-linked-list

Answer (score 2):

You can't. You can only recommend the list as a candidate for garbage collection by removing all *references* to it.

If you own the only reference then setting that reference to `null` will schedule the object for garbage collection. You can *advise* a garbage collection using `System.gc()` but that's not particularly good style and not all JVMs support it.

Removing the elements node by node (use `clear()`) *can* help a little since it will reduce the number of references held on each of the list items. That will reduce the amount of memory that the list consumes.

Answer (score 0):

You can point the `LinkedList` reference variable to `null`.

Any reference variable referring to `null` is automatically eligible for *Garbage Collection*

```
List list = new LinkedList();
list.add("hi");
list = null; // now eligible for *Garbage Collection*, leave it for JVM to handle
```

Moreover if you do `list.clear()` it will clear all the elements inside this `list` but not the `list` itself.

Also we can call `System.gc()` but `System.gc()` will not ensure that Garbage Collector will run for sure, it can only asks the JVM to run the GC , but is totally dependent on JVM, so we should levae it to JVM only to handle GC.

For more info see this Oracle Doc [here](http://docs.oracle.com/cd/E19159-01/819-3681/abebi/index.html)

Comment: A reference referring to ``null`` does not point to anything, hence cannot be garbage collected... But the ``new LinkedList`` can be, because **there are no more references to it**

Comment: @BinkanSalaryman who told you this point. This is wrong. check the Oracle Link here http://docs.oracle.com/cd/E19159-01/819-3681/abebi/index.html

Comment: I was actually talking about *Reference Variable* like `list` in the above example is a reference variable which initially refers to `LinkedList` and finally to a `null`

Answer (score 0):

Yes, you can simply assign the `head` as `null` but to be on the safe side (as in if some nodes are being referred from elsewhere) it is better to make all nodes `null`.

If you look at the code in `java.util.LinkedList`, the clear() method does the same.

```
/**
 * Removes all of the elements from this list.
 * The list will be empty after this call returns.
 */
public void clear() {
    // Clearing all of the links between nodes is "unnecessary", but:
    // - helps a generational GC if the discarded nodes inhabit
    //   more than one generation
    // - is sure to free memory even if there is a reachable Iterator
    for (Node<E> x = first; x != null; ) {
        Node<E> next = x.next;
        x.item = null;
        x.next = null;
        x.prev = null;
        x = next;
    }
    first = last = null;
    size = 0;
    modCount++;
}
```

`first` reference is `head` in your case.

You can also refer to this [comprehensive answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/31070498/1385441).